# Problems with NSOpenPanel and massive memory leak

Tags: swift, macos-mojave

I am developing a GUI for rsync (RsyncOSX) and in next version the plan is add a GUI for choosing catalogs. I have some time ago experienced some stability issues utilizing NSOpenPanel but now I wanted to try again. But still there seems to issues utilizing NSOpenPanel, the console is producing the following error:

Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit (0x7fff8c017210) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (0x10f1d5dc8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I have also run the app through Xcode instruments and checked for memory leaks and every time opening the NSOpenPanel there is a huge memory leak..

[image]

Has anyone found a workaround? The code for opening the GUI is very simple :

```
private func openfiledlg (title: String, message: String) {
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.prompt = "Select"
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
    openPanel.canCreateDirectories = true
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
    openPanel.resolvesAliases = true
    openPanel.title = title
    openPanel.message = message
    if self.modal {
        let OK = openPanel.runModal()
        if OK.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {
            self.urlpath = openPanel.url
        }
    } else {
        openPanel.begin(completionHandler: { response in
            if response.rawValue == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
                self.urlpath = openPanel.url
            }
            openPanel.close()
        })
    }

}
```

Setting weak var openPanel = NSOpenPanel() only reduces the memory leak..

Answer (score 1):

If the window is set to be released when closed, a release message is sent to the object after the current event is completed. For an NSWindow object, the default is to be released on closing, while for an NSPanel object, the default is not to be released. You can use the `isReleasedWhenClosed` property to change the default behavior.

Comment: adding openPanel.isReleasedWhenClosed = true does not solve the memory leak... the leak is still huge...

Comment: what happen if you close the openModal inside the second `if`? after `self.urlpath = openPanel.url`

Comment: Switching on the Sandbox environment does the magic, the memory leaks disappear and the error message in console (see top of question) as well.. But that makes my app useless because all Sandbox restrictions causes problems reading files from the home catalog...

Comment: After working some time with macOS app sandboxing it now works.. The only drawback now is macOS is shipped with old version of rsync and utilizing snapshots require an updated version of rsync... The sandbox does not allow executing third party command line tools (at least of my knowlegde) outside the sandbox..